# The law of the iterated logarithm for BM and boundedness of stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

My question is regarding the usefulness of the law of the iterated logarithm, and its connection to stopping times. In many answers of this forum, I understand that some people often claim that some stopping times, such as
$$\tau_n = \inf\left\{t \geq 0 : B_t = n\right\}
$$
are finite almost surely *because of the law of the iterated logarithm*. I am familiar with the law of course, but I don't really see how we can argue that any stopping time is bounded if, say, in the example above $n$ is very large.

This takes me to ask the following two questions: does the law assure that $\mathscr{F}_{t}$-measurable stopping times are **always** bounded? Is there an example when the Law of the Iterated Logarithm doesn't help us to conclude that a stopping time is **not bounded** almost surely?

Comment: For this particular example, using the LIL is overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The law of the iterated logarithm states that almost surely:
$$ \limsup_{t \to \infty} \frac{|B_t|}{\sqrt{2t\log(\log(t))}} = 1 $$

So asymptotically we have that $|B_t| \approx  \sqrt{2t\log(\log(t))}$, and in particular $\limsup_{t \to \infty} |B_t| = \infty$. Since $P(B_t > 0, \forall t > 0) = 0$, the brownian motion must cross infinite times the zero line (use the Markov property), and since $\limsup_{t \to \infty} |B_t| = \infty$ we have that $\limsup B_t = \infty$ and $\liminf B_t = -\infty$. Finally by continuity of the paths you can conclude that any level $c$ must be attained.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Using this same argument, can you give an example of a stopping time that can't be bounded using this law?

Comment: Hand waving a little bit: An Orstein-Uhlenbeck process driven by a $F_t$-Brownian motion is a a $F_t$-semi martingale and thus its first passage times $\tau_n'$ are $F_t$ stopping times. But the OU processes converges almost surely to its $\mu$ parameter, and there will be first passage times $\tau_n'$ that have positive probability of being infinite.

Comment: It is not very rigorous to say "and in particular $|B_t|\rightarrow\infty$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$". What do you mean by that? Also, the OU processes converge to a stationary distribution which is centered around $\mu$, they do not "converge almost surely to their parameter". An example of a stopping time of the Brownian motion that "can't be bounded with the law of the iterated logarithm" would be $\inf\{t\ge0\ :\ B_t=t\}$, i.e. the hitting time of the line $y=x$ by the BM. This stopping time is not finite almost surely.

Comment: Maybe some confusion is also arising because you think the stopping times are bounded. **They are not**. In general, even the hitting time of a level $n$ is unbounded. It can only be shown to be finite almost surely.

Comment: @Ian you are right. I'll correct it.

Comment: I fail to see the argument to deduce $\limsup B=+\infty$ and $\liminf B=-\infty$ from $\limsup|B|=+\infty$.